# Coordinates of the vertices of a five-pointed star

Tags: coordinate-systems

I'm trying to draw a five-pointed star; I have one pair of coordinates (I currently have that at the center of the star) and the "width" of the star.

Now, I've tried a lot around, but I can't figure out a way to find all 10 coordinates just based on these numbers.

I also need to rotate the star at angle x, so i need a way to change the coordinates.

(the thing is done through a custom library in python, but i just need a way to get these coordinates)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the tips you want to have 5 points evenly spread around a cycle with radius $r$, so take $$\{(r\cos(2\pi k/5+\pi/2),r\sin(2\pi k/5+\pi/2)) \mid k=0,...,4\}$$Do the same for the inner five points, but use a smaller radius and an additional $+2\pi/10$ within $\cos$ and $\sin$ to make them half way between the tips. (I have added $\pi/2$ to make the first tip point up, instead of right...)

Answer (score 3):

Prett much the same approach provided already, but I've included a diagram and gave the information in degrees rather than radians.

[image: Two circles with a star inlaid]

As you can see in the image, the coordinates are generated on an inner and outer circle.  The radius of the smaller circle in the image is 2 units and the radius of the larger outer circle is 6 units.  Each coordinate on the outer circle is $72^\circ$ around the circle from the previous coordinate.  I started at $18^\circ$ so that a star point would be at $18^\circ+72^\circ=90^\circ$.  The inner circle coordinates started at $54^\circ$ because it is the median angle of $18^\circ$ and $90^\circ$.

Every coordinate is written $(r~cos(\Theta),~r~sin(\Theta))$